# Optimization of two vectors in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I need to do an optimization of two vectors **x** and **y**, the objective function is a function of these two vectors f(**x,y**) and **x** and **y** are also related with a-**x**/**y** =0, is there a well-known method to solve this on python?

Comment: What is `a`? What have you tried here? What does "optimization" mean in this context? This sorta sounds like a homework problem - What techniques are required of you? You've tagged this with scipy, does that mean you've written something on your own? Please share the relevant sections so that we have something to work with from you.

Comment: We can't help you when we don't know exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is general, it'd be great if you provide more details. But I grabbed a code snippet from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html), where you can edit. scipy has a class optimize which has a couple of methods to optimize functions.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x,y):
  return 10 - x/y

# initial values
x0 = 1.3
y0 = 0.5

res = minimize(f, [x0, y0], method='...')
print(res.x)
```

If you provide more info like what algorithm you want to use, I can provide more precise code.

Comment: I assumed a is a constant with value 10.